# Error adding listview items

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

Listview items stopped getting updated on my list automatically. I did not have to use notifydatasetchanged() when adding list items and it was getting updated without refreshing the screen. But after adding a database reference to my code, the listview updates only when I lock and unlock my phone. I tried commenting out the databsereference code, but it still doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

UPDATE: I have attached the code below. After using notifydatasetchanged() the list gets automatically updated but all the listview items change to the most recently added item.

```
    ListView=findViewById(R.id.swipemenu);
      HashMap<String,String> item = new HashMap<String,String>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list=new 
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
   SimpleAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
            R.layout.simplelist,
            new String[] { "line1","line2" },
            new int[] {R.id.text1, R.id.text2});
    ListView.setAdapter(adapter);

  item.put( "line1",result.getContents() );
                item.put( "line2","Qty:1" );
                list.add( item );
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (result != null) {
        if (result.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Result Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result.getContents());

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                item.put( "line1",result.getContents() );
                item.put( "line2","Qty:1" );
                list.add( item );
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not right case, debug code

Comment: Post your activity code.

Comment: I posted  the code.

Comment: Have you used `onResume` or `onRestart` methods in your activity class?

Comment: No, only the item gets added inside OnActivityResult()

Comment: Please post that method code.

Comment: Posted the method code

Comment: Why you are not use Json Data from JSONObject?

Comment: You are trying to add item in `catch` instead of `try` block.

Comment: Thats not relevant. Using the Json Data doesn't affect the listview in any way.

Comment: The OnActivityResult is used to get qrscanner data. When the returned data from the scanner does not match a specific json format, the data gets printed out in the catch block.

Comment: Put break-point on `OnActivityResult` and check with unlock phone.

Comment: Try in onActivityResult() before `item.put( "line1",result.getContents() );` add: `item = new HashMap<String,String>();` Hope that helps!